# Erro ao enviar formulário ao pressionar Enter - PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

boa noite. Estou com um problema ao submeter um formulário, ao teclar Enter retorna o erro: "Undefined Index" do php. Porém, se eu clicar no botão Logar, ele submete normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(function() {
    $('.form').form({
      fields: {
        usuario: {
          identifier: 'usuario',
          rules: [{
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Preencha o campo Usuário!'
          }]
        },

        senha: {
          identifier: 'senha',
          rules: [{
            type: 'empty',
            prompt: 'Preencha o campo Senha!'
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  }); <
/script>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4 !important;
}

.login-alerts {
  width: 350;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.login-center {
  width: 350px;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 8%;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 8px 1px #d6d6d6;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.login-logo {
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.login {
  padding: 10px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/master/dist/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/master/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <div class="login-center">
    <div class="login-top">
      <div class="login-logo"><img src="assets/img/sigio-logo.svg" width="150"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="login">
      <form class="ui form error" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="field ui fluid left icon input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Usuário" id="usuario" name="usuario" maxlength="15">
          <i class="user icon"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="field ui fluid left icon input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Senha" id="senha" name="senha" maxlength="25">
          <i class="lock icon"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <input type="submit" class="fluid ui primary button" name="logar" value="Logar">
        </div>

        <div class="ui error message"></div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Também deveria colocar o código PHP, afinal de contas o erro está nele. Ps.: Para corrigir adicione o campo `logar` no *JavaScript*.

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo o que diz a mensagem, alguma variável com o nome "logar" não foi definida.

Tente usar algo como:

```
if( isset($_POST['logar']) ){
   // Seu código
}
```

Isso fará com que seja verificada a existência do campo "logar" e a mensagem de "notice" não seja exibida por conta disso. Quando a existência do mesmo não é verificado e o interpretador do PHP emite o **E_NOTICE** .

Uma outra alternativa seria colocar um @ antes de iniciar no nome da variável, da seguinte maneira:

```
@$logar = $_POST['logar'];
//ou
$logar = @$_POST['logar'];
```

Contudo, não é recomendado que isso seja feito por que ocultar erros do tipo **E_NOTICE** principalmente é gambiarra. O que se deve fazer é cercar todas as possibilidades de erros, gerando mensagens personalizadas.

Por isso foi necessária aquela verificação de existência.

E para finalizar, você não precisa definir um valor para o botão que envia os dados do formulário.

A definição do nome do botão já é o suficiente.

```
<input type="submit" class="fluid ui primary button" name="logar">
```